# How long to wait for a reply from the SE staff?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, user-accounts, best-practices, help-center

> After having contacted the SE staff and not having received an answer, how long should I wait before contacting them again with the same request?

In May and June I have received the baptism of serial downvoting of several of my questions. I contacted the SE staff, they analyzed the situation and fully restored my reputation (and also sent me an answer by email). The downvoting, though, continued for a while. It now seems to have stopped, so I contacted the SE staff once more a week ago. Since then, nothing happened to my reputation and no answer has been received from them. How long should I wait before contacting them again with the same request, in order for me not to be considered rude or aggressive?

Comment: FWIW: I investigated your case. It is, indeed, the same user. The total number of downvotes is so-so. It is not entirely obvious to me that it is targeted voting, but the weight of history pulls in that direction. My suggestion is that you flag a few downvoted posts.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: 7 minutes ago my reputation got restored and I also received a message from the SE staff. Did you have anything to do with it?

Comment: No. I didn't do anything. Diamond moderators could delete a user, and that would void their votes, but that is something we should only do in more extreme cases.

Comment: Serial downvoting, that's rude! Is someone using the script by [this user(OP)](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36717/whats-the-secret-word-interactive-hangman-puzzle?noredirect=1#comment118288_36717)?